# How to get the value of the user input to href it?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the value of the input to make it as an HREF, for example, the user input is 192.168.1.1, I want to redirect to that input as the button is clicked so I can go directly to that IP address here is my code:

```js
function displayCam()
{
    var ip = document.getElementById('ipadd');
    document.getElementById('camView').innerHTML = ip.value;
}
```

```html
<h1>Input IP Address</h1>
<label for="ipadd">Enter IP Address:</label>
<input type='text' id='ipadd' />
<input type='button' onclick='displayCam()' value='Submit' />   
<div id="camView"> </div>
```

Comment: You have ' value='Submit' /> value='Submit' />' double, please edit and change that typo.

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.location.href = ip.value;`

Comment: Thanks but as i press the submit button it is looking for the input text in my local files is there any other way i can go directly to that site in browser? For example someone input facebook.com or my IP CAM address is is there another method that i could go there directly?

Answer (score 2):

To redirect to the ip address they added, you could modify `displayCam` to look like this:

```
function displayCam()
{
    var ip = document.getElementById('ipadd');
    document.getElementById('camView').innerHTML = ip.value;
    if (ip.value.indexOf('://') === -1) {
        ip.value = "http://" + ip.value; // Use http by default
    }
    window.location.href = ip.value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it seems like it is looking for the ip.value in my local files, i want to go directly to the website in the internet or for example i type facebook.com it can go directly to that website  or the ip address, it is displaying a message in my browser that your file was not found is there any way i can do that?

Comment: I just updated the code sample. This should do it. I suspect it was failing because there was no protocol being used in front of the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

Put **anchor** tag inside the **div** and set **href** dynamically on button click

```
<script>
function displayCam()
{
    var ip = document.getElementById('ipadd');
    document.getElementById('camView').innerHTML = ip.value;
    document.getElementById('camView').href="http://"+ip.value;

    //Or to open in new tab on submit button directly 
    var url="http://"+ip.value;
    window.open(url)
}
</script>

<h1>Input IP Address</h1>
<label for="ipadd">Enter IP Address:</label>
    <input type='text' id='ipadd' />
    <input type='button' onclick='displayCam()' value='Submit' />

<div><a href="" id="camView" target="_blank" ></a></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help it worked, but can I put this code snippet inside the submit button? so as I click the submit button it goes directly where the href is?

Code:




<div><a href="" id="camView" target="_blank" ></a></div>

Comment: You can use window.open("url") methos inside your displayCam() method. So it will open this link directly. Here "url" would be like this var url="http://"+ip.value;